# Android App with Firebase [Database Problem]

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A few days ago I began programming an app in "Android Studio".

I recently found Firebase which I wanted to use as an database. My problem now is no matter how I write my code nothing will be written into the "Realtime Database". Sometime my App crashes completely and sometimes there is an endless loop of loading.

If there is anyone out there who could help to write into my database
The structure should be the Following:

Users:
--UID:
----age:
----email:
----fullname:

Here is my code, maybe someone can find my misstake.

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegisterUser extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView banner, registerUser;
    private EditText editTextFullName, editTextAge, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth databaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);

        databaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        banner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
        banner.setOnClickListener(this);

        registerUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerUser);
        registerUser.setOnClickListener(this);

        editTextFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.banner:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.registerUser:
                registerUser();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String fullName = editTextFullName.getText().toString().trim();
        String age = editTextAge.getText().toString().trim();

        if (fullName.isEmpty()){
            editTextFullName.setError("Bitte ausfüllen.");
            editTextFullName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (age.isEmpty()){
            editTextAge.setError("Bitte ausfüllen.");
            editTextAge.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (email.isEmpty()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Bitte ausfüllen.");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Bitte eine gültige Email-Adresse angeben.");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(password.isEmpty()){
            editTextPassword.setError("Bitte ausfüllen.");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6){
            editTextPassword.setError("Password muss mindestens aus 6 Zeichen bestehen.");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        databaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(fullName, age, email);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Registrierung erfolgreich!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten! Versuch es erneut.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten! Versuch es erneut.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
                });


    }

}```
````

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: If your database was created in Europe or Asia and if you did so after downloading the `google-services.json` file, you'll have to redownload that file and update it in your Android app. Alternatively, you can pass the URL of your database to `getInstance(...)` like this: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here").getReference("Users")`.